# using wp_get_attachment_image_src in foreach loop

Tags: loop, images

I have 10 images added to a post via Advanced Custom Fields, they're named from 1 to 10 e.g 'image_*', ACF is set to return the ID.

I'm trying to get the full size image URL of each image in the loop and use it as a `href` attribute to open a full size popup of the image, however I don't understand how wp_get_attachment_image_src works.

Since I am unable to use Advanced Custom Field's Repeater, this is the loop i'm using to get an array of the images with a custom image size of `scaled`, it works fine to generate the responsive image markup that I need:

```
// args    

$sizeHuge = 'scaled'; // scaled image  
$images = array(); // img array

for($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) { 
        $img = get_field('image_' . $x);
   if($img) {
        $images[] = $img; 
   } else {
        break;
   }
 }


<?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>

    <a href="" class="open-viewer">

        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $sizeHuge ); ?>

    </a>

<?php } ?>
```

I need to set the `href` attribute of the parent `a` element with the URL of the image. This is what I have tried with wp_get_attachment_image_src, it doesn't work, it sets every `href` with `image_10`'s URL.

```
// args

$sizeFull = 'full'; // full size image
$sizeHuge = 'scaled'; // scaled image  
$images = array(); // img array

for($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) { 
        $img = get_field('image_' . $x);
        $image_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img, $sizeFull);
        $link = $image_array[0];                
   if($img) {
        $images[] = $img; 
   } else {
        break;
   }
 }


<?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="open-viewer">

        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $sizeHuge ); ?>

    </a>

<?php } ?>
```

**My question is: How can I set the `href` of `a.open-viewer` with the correct URL?, and secondly, why does my code fail? (debug is switched on but no errors appear).**

I realise I've horribly misunderstood something here, I'm a PHP novice so any advice about my approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your first loop why do you break it? if there is no image in `image_5` if someone just skip this and continue to `image_6`?

Second the ACF image field can return you an array with all the sizes. you need to set the field to return you **Image Array**

And then you can do something like this.

```
for($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) { 
    $img = get_field('image_' . $x);
    if($img) {
        ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $img['url']; ?>" class="open-viewer">
                <img src="<?php echo $img['sizes']['scaled']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $img['alt']; ?>">
            </a>
        <?php
    }
}
```

In case you can't return **Image Array** and you return the **Image ID**

```
for($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) { 
    $img_id = get_field('image_' . $x);
    if($img_id) {
        $fullsize_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_id, 'full');
        ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $fullsize_image[0]; ?>" class="open-viewer">
                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($img_id, 'scaled'); ?>
            </a>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sadly I'm not able to change the ACF return value to Image Array, I must use the image ID.

Comment: I edited the answer and gave you the other option for image id

Comment: Thank you, this works! Can you explain a little more about the first part of your answer please? 'First in your first loop why do you break it? if there is no image in image_5 if someone just skip this and continue to image_6?' I'm a PHP novice, thanks for your help

Comment: I meant in this what if someone will fill fields `image_1` and `image_3` but didn't fill the field `image_2` in that case in your code you break the loop and then `image_3` won't show... so better to continue the loop. its good also if you want to delete some image in the middle and leave it empty.

Comment: I see what you mean now, that's exactly what I *don't* want to happen! I just tested this scenario with your code and it works perfectly. Thank you for your help with the problem and your ability to spot a potential future problem!